# range as object in a cell and vlookup

Tags: vba, excel

Is there any way I can store a range as an object handle in excel, and then do a vlookup on the handle?
For example:
in cell D1 `=create_range(A1:C10)`, and then in cell E1 `=vlookup_range("foo",D1,2,FALSE)`.

Comment: Are you looking for something that's like a named range, but can be changed by just changing a cell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **D1** enter:

```
A1:C10
```

In **E1** enter:

```
=VLOOKUP("foo",INDIRECT(D1),2)
```

[image]

or use a *Named Range* without the helper cell.

Comment: Named range is preferred, since that is a range handle and will respond to moves, resizes, etc.

Comment: @rdhs I agree completely.